# performSegueWithIdentifier in swift

Tags: swift, uistoryboardsegue

If I have this Objective C code:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"push" sender:self];
```

and

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"push"]) {

}
```

What is the Swift equivalent?

Comment: i use self.preformSegueWithIdentifier("push", self)
syntax error : 'ViewController' does not have a member named 'preformSegueWithIdentifier'

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("push", sender: self)

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
if segue.identifier == "push" {

}
```

You have a typo in your `self.preformSegueWithIdentifier`

Comment: My tutorial covers this in great detail as well, http://jamesonquave.com/blog/developing-ios-8-apps-using-swift-interaction-with-multiple-views/

Comment: The first parameter doesn't need to be unwrapped, so don't use the `!`

Comment: The correct answer to this question would be rather: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("push", sender: self)

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if (segue.identifier == "push") {

}}